# XSLT, display PCDATA as CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt

Thanks for looking.

I am trying to write an .xsl file that will generate HTML, to make it easier to error check our .xml files, by showing only the text that has an applicability code.

The normal viewer application for our XML will filter content based on applicability codes in the XML.  (The applicability codes represent individual vehicle models.)  There is no way to disable the filtering in the viewer application, which means that potentially someone has to check every file multiple times (once for each applicability code) to ensure it is correct for every model.

I have xml data with tags nested in it:

```
    <para>Disconnect main chassis wire harness connector 
MC57 (<xref applicable="UOC_GP0 UOC_HG0 UOC_WC0 UOC_2U0" 
figid="F01"/><xref applicable="UOC_GP1 UOC_HG1 UOC_WC1 
UOC_2U1" figid="F01A"/>, Item 3) from main cab wire 
harness connector MC57 (<xref applicable="UOC_GP0 
UOC_HG0 UOC_WC0 UOC_2U0" figid="F01"/>
<xref applicable="UOC_GP1 UOC_HG1 UOC_WC1 UOC_2U1" 
figid="F01A"/>, Item 2).</para>
```

The relevant xsl is pretty simple:

```
<xsl:for-each select="para">
&#160;&#160;&#160;Step1 Para&#58;&#160;&#160;
<xsl:value-of select="." /><br />
</xsl:for-each>
```

but that filters out the xref tags and leaves the output as:

```
Step1 Para:   Disconnect main chassis wire harness connector 
MC57 ( , Item 3) from main cab wire harness connector MC57 ( , Item 2).
```

The output is correct for how the xsl is written, but not what I want.

I would like the output to include the xref tags and their attributes that are mixed into the para, as written:

```
    Disconnect main chassis wire harness connector 
MC57 (<xref applicable="UOC_GP0 UOC_HG0 UOC_WC0 UOC_2U0" 
figid="F01"/><xref applicable="UOC_GP1 UOC_HG1 UOC_WC1 
UOC_2U1" figid="F01A"/>, Item 3) from main cab wire 
harness connector MC57 (<xref applicable="UOC_GP0 
UOC_HG0 UOC_WC0 UOC_2U0" figid="F01"/>
<xref applicable="UOC_GP1 UOC_HG1 UOC_WC1 UOC_2U1" 
figid="F01A"/>, Item 2).
```

Which is ugly, but would let the reviwers know that there are xrefs with applicability in the para.

Is there a way, in the xsl, to signal that the processor should treat the contents of the  tag as CDATA rather than PCDATA?  That seems like the obvious solution, but I am not finding a way to do that.

Or some other way to go about this?  With the xref tags embedded at random in the para tags, I am kind of stumped.

Thanks

Comment: So which version of XSLT, which XSLT processor do you use? If the output is HTML but you want to present the XML markup of some nodes in the input then you need to serialize them, which is possible in XSLT 3 (as supported by the open source Saxon 9.8 HE) doing e.g. `<xsl:value-of select="serialize(node())"/>` instead of the `value-of` you have.

Comment: You could also do an `xsl:apply-templates` and match `xref` and serialize it yourself.

Comment: To me, the obvious solution is to transform all the children of each `<para>` (including text-node children) instead of outputting its string value, pretty much as the one answer you've received so far demonstrates.  Certainly that's the most *natural* solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Displaying as XML**

If you want to make all the xref elements elements visible using their XML syntax, you can write something like this; I've specified class attributes on various elements so you can tweak the display.  (I've also written a template for para, rather than a for-each, because I think excessive use of for-each tends to lead to horrible stylesheets.  Change it back if you prefer it.)  This is what Daniel Haley's comment is talking about.

```
<xsl:template match="para">
  <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;Step1 Para&#58;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
  <br/>
</

<xsl:template match="xref">
  <span class="xmlsource">
    <span class="start-tag">
      <xsl:text>&lt;</xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <xsl:text>/&gt;</
    </span>
  </span>
</

<xsl:template match="xref/@*">
  <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
  <xsl:text>="</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
  <xsl:text>"</xsl:text>
</
```

**False-color display**

If it were me, I'd probably prefer to see a more intuitive display:  show the applicable figid value, with a color background to set it off -- or if at seems likely `figid="F01"` means "display figure F01 here", show the figure itself.  (I'll leave the latter as an exercise for you.)

The code below assumes that the current applicability codes are given in the global variable `$appcodes` as a sequence of strings.

```
<xsl:template match="xref">
  <xsl:if test="tokenize(@applicable) = $appcodes">
    <span class="xref-fig">
      <xsl:value-of select="@figid"/>
    </
  </
</
```

This kind of display used for proof checking and not intended to match what the end user of the final product will see is often called a false-color proof.